# Send Input values from one page to another

Tags: php, html, laravel

I'm working on Laravel project and I want to send my input values from the FORM from one page (the inscription page) to a pdf page (which I want the user to be able to download).  I couldn't find a way to send them from that page to the other

input:all 
using the `$request` in the **controller**

```
<div class="fieldgroup">
                            <input type="text" style="color:0B0C51" onclick="submitform2()" name="cin" id="cin"
                                    placeholder="N°CIN" maxlength="8" class="required"></i><br>

                    </div>


                    <div class="fieldgroup">
                            <input type="text" style="color:0B0C51" v-model="prenom" name="prenom" id="prenom"
                                    placeholder="Prenom" class="required"><br>
                    </div>


                    <div class="fieldgroup">
                            <input type="text" style="color:0B0C51" v-model="nom" onclick="submitform2()" name="nom"
                                    id="nom" placeholder="Nom" class="required"><br>
                    </div>

                    <div class="fieldgroup">
                            <input type="mail" style="color:0B0C51" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email"
                                    class="required" />

                    </div>
```

**ViewController** :

```
    class ViewController extends Controller
{

public function generatePDF(Request $request){
    $request=this.
    $data="form";
    $pdf= PDF::loadView('pdf',compact('data'));
    return $pdf->download('Terms.pdf');
}
```

}

**web.php**:

```
       Route::get('/pdf','ViewController@generatePDF');
```

**inscriController:**

```
public function store(Request $request)
{   
    $cin = $request->input('cin');
    $data = array(['cin'=>$cin ]);

    DB::table('form')->insert($data);

    return redirect('/pdf')->withInput();
```

This returns an empty form page without the input values

Answer (score 0):

It may be easier to load the pdf right in the `store` method of **inscriController**.  As it is, you are redirecting *and passing no data into the pdf generator / view*.  You set `$request` as the controller (`$this`), which has none of the form data, and then you pass a single word 'form' as your data-set into the PDF generator.  I don't think this will work the way you wish - I assume the pdf view is looking for specific variables (not 'form'), and thus it is failing because those vars are missing.  IE you'd want to pull those vars like `$name = $request->get('name')` and pass whatever pdf.blade.php view needs from your `$request` var.

If you don't want to do it all in the `store` function, perhaps pass it to a method in the same **inscriController**?  This way you can easily push the actual request object into that method and pull the fields you need for the PDF view.

Comment: thank u for ur time, but i don't actually understand what u mean, can u give a link or some code to work on?

Comment: The main problem I think is that you are not passing any variables to your pdf view.  You are passing a string (literally the word 'form' is going to the view), not a variable.  Take a look at your view (pdf) and see what variables it needs.  Then, you need to pull those variables from the $request object and send them to the view through the compact function.  Like if you need the var `$name` on the view, then set `$name` in the controller and pass it: `$pdf= PDF::loadView('pdf',compact('name'));`

Answer (score 0):

use `$input = $request->all();` for getting the data and in same function instead of redirect u can just return view for your /pdf route.

like `return view('yourpath.pdf', compact('input'));`

Comment: thank u for ur respond, but i tried it and it didn't work